# Dharma Himsa Tathaiva Cha

Tags: scripture

I would like to know if the statement ***Dharma Himsa Tathaiva Cha*** is authentic and if it has any scriptural reference. I know that ***Ahimsa Paramo Dharmah*** is a statement from the Mahabharata. Other than Swami Chinmayananda's article (wherein he does not provide any scriptural reference) I haven't found any reference for ***Dharma Himsa Tathaiva Cha***.

Just to be clear, by scriptures I mean The Upanishads, Puranas, Gita etc..not articles written by Swamis, Gurus etc..

Thanks !

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/does-the-shloka-ahi%E1%B9%83s%C4%81-paramo-dharma-or-excerpt-appear-in-mahabharata