# Why Hindus never invaded anyone in 10000 years History?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, dharma, brahmins

Why Hindus haven't invaded anyone on their 10000 years of history?

Comment: [This](http://www.hinduismtoday.com/modules/smartsection/item.php?itemid=3065) could be reason. Crossing ocean or India is consider as Sin in Ancient times. There's a story of King in *Bhavishya Purana* in which Lord Shiva warned that King (forgot his name) not cross Himalayas as Mleccha Religion (Adharmic) was reigning there. However, we can't trust completely Bhavishya Puarana as it was highly interpolated by Persian invaders and Britishers.

Comment: The information provided here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_India may throw a light on your (false) supposition.  See India-Bhutan for example (Bhutanese territorial cessions to India). Also, the 10000 years of history is vague, maybe you shall define better the time interval you have in mind. Also read others opinions here https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-India-has-never-invaded-any-foreign-country

Comment: India was very big, if you talk about Afghanistan, Bhutan and ShriLanka it was part of Ancient Bharat

Comment: Chola empire colonized south east Asia (Malaysia, Java, Sumatra, etc).

Comment: @Ikshvaku Good Example, i would add that Chola empire mainly used their overwhelming navy to display a threat of force than actually utilising the full force of their battalions.

Comment: This is not true i guess. Chola empire ruled South east Asia. I think it is kind of invasion only but not cruel or fanatic.

Comment: @TheDestroyer May not be a brutal or violent invasion but they still took over territory that initially didn't belong to them. OP asked "why Hindus never *invade* anyone"? You can still invade without bloodshed, aka Russian take over of Crimea in 2014, it basically met with zero resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> अहिंसा परमो धर्मः धर्म हिंसा तथैव च: |

Non-violence is the ultimate dharma. So too is violence in service of Dharma.

Hence, we never attacked others but responded whenever it was required.

Comment: See [Does the shloka 'ahiṃsā paramo dharma' or excerpt appear in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9339/3500)