# Does the Mahabharata contain the quote "When is peace not peace?"

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, identification-request, war, ahimsa

Yesterday I was listening to an American political radio show, and I was surprised to hear a reference to Hinduism.  An African American activist who was being interviewed said the following:

> In an Indian spiritual text called the Mahabharata, someone asked a question "When is peace not peace?" And Arjuna answered "When it is tyranny."

The activist was using the quote to make a point about relations between blacks and whites in America, but my question is, does any such quote occur in the Mahabharata?

I can imagine Arjuna saying that peace is not peace when it is tyranny, to describe why it is necessary to fight the Kauravas rather than just living in peace under the rule of the Kauravas. I can also imagine something like this occurring in a dialogue between Arjuna and Krishna (inside or outside the Bhagavad Gita) with Arjuna asking the question and Krishna answering it, and the activist might have misremembered it as Arjuna answering.  Or this quote could have no scriptural basis.

Comment: Something related was said by Indra. `Indra said, 'Upon the disappearance of kingly duties and of the science of chastisement, all creatures became exceedingly afflicted, O sinless one, in consequence of the tyranny of kings.` [RajadharmanusAsana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a064.htm).

Comment: @iammilind What does that have to do with peace?

Comment: *"all creatures became exceedingly **afflicted**, ... in consequence of the **tyranny** of kings."* -- the meaning of "afflict" is "to suffer". So, when there is a suffering, there is no peace of mind. Which means -- due to tyranny of kings, people tend to lose their peace of mind.

Comment: As per [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/734/4732) post you have already read Vyasa's Mahabharata, then how come you yourself don't know the answer yet?

Comment: Do you really believe in words of any person quoting anything taking names of Indian Scriptures. Even in india, people keep on saying in that Puraana it is that written. Tgey have not even seen the Puraana. The Activist may not even know who wrote MahaBharata.

Comment: @Rickross Because I don't know it by heart.

Comment: @AnuragSingh No, I don't necessarily believe him, I'm just trying to find out if he's right.

Comment: Usually people start quoting their own philosophies taking hold of Scriptures. But yes, This quote 'when is per not peace. When tyranny is there' might be said by Arjun somewhere, but not necessarily the Activist might be knowing it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It is not required of u to remember it. Nobody remembers a huge text like MB by heart. But if u have read it, then you will certainly have faint memories of it. And which is sufficient to answer Qs like " where is this found in MB?".

Comment: @Rickross I certainly have lots of knowledge and memory of the Mahabharata, but not to the extent that for every single quote X in the Mahabharata, I would be able to answer, is X in the Mahabharata or not.  (Although I would be able to answer it for many important or memorable quotes.) It seems like the sort of line that occurs in the Udyoga Parva of the Mahabharata in the prelude to the war, but I don't know whether this specific line occurs or not.  The general sentiment behind the line, that some forms of peace are intolerable, is certainly something that occurs in the Udyoga Parva.