# "Peace is reserved for the worthy....if Adharma wants war, Dharma will give it war!" is this quote from the Gita or any other Hindu Scriptures?

Tags: scripture, krishna, bhagavad-gita, dharma, adharma

[image: PEACE IS RESERVED ONLY FOR WORTHY. WHEN YOU OFFER PEACE TO EVIL, IT THROWS IT RIGHT BACK. IF ADHARMA WANTS WAR, DHARMA WILL GIVE IT WAR!]

"PEACE IS RESERVED ONLY FOR WORTHY. WHEN YOU OFFER PEACE TO EVIL, IT THROWS IT RIGHT BACK. IF ADHARMA WANTS WAR, DHARMA WILL GIVE IT WAR!"

I have seen this quote on the internet often attributed to the Hindu texts or the Bhagavad Gita itself or Lord Krishna..is there anywhere that this quote, in its meaning or spirit ever mentioned in any of Hindu religious scriptures ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think, You can check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/does-the-shloka-ahi%E1%B9%83s%C4%81-paramo-dharma-or-excerpt-appear-in-mahabharata) question along with its comments and answers. Prd.. ...

Comment: unaware of this being from any Hindu scripture